# Opening a file into a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, file, jlabel

I want to create a program which allows the user to input a file name and then it shows everything written in the file in a JLabel, I have managed to find/create code which allows the user to input the name of the file and then show the contents of the file in the console but I couldn't find a way to show everything from the text file in a JLabel.

Is there a way to do this? As some people have told me that it is not possible to do this.

Comment: Using a JLabel sounds like a bad idea.  I think a JTextPane is a better choice. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html

Comment: This really doesn't make sense. A JLabel is for displaying a single line of text, not a lot of text or multiple lines of text, and your question looks to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) question where you're asking how to do something using a completely wrong and impossible approach. Much better to tell about the overall thing you're trying to do and not the incorrect way that you're trying to do it.

Comment: What about `jLabel.setText(fileContent);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes...it is possible but as already mentioned you would be far better off using the JTextArea or similar component instead and most likely save yourself some grief.

Although a JLabel is basically designed for a single string line of text it does allow for that text to be wrapped within HTML tags therefore allowing for basic HTML/CSS to format that same text. The trick then is to read each line of a desired text file into a single string variable formatting that string as you append each line read and, by formatting, I mean adding:

- A Title;
- Line Breaks;
- Indenting;
- Left Marginal Padding;
- Line Wrapping;
- Bold, Italics, Underlining;
- Fonts, Font Style, Font Sizes, and even Font Colors;
- Text alignments like Left, Center, Right, and Justify;
- etc, etc, etc.

A JLabel doesn't recognize the usual line breaks you're already familiar with like `"\n"` or `"\r\n"` or even `System.lineSeparator();`. It will however deal with the HTML Line Break tag of `<br>` **but only** if the text being applied to the JLabel is wrapped within HTML. Here is an example of a two line JLabel text:

```
String txt = "<html>This is line one.<br>This is line two.</html>";
jLabel1.setText(txt);
```

Ultimately your JLabel would look something like this:

[image]

Notice in the code line above that the String text starts with `<html>` and ends with `</html>`. Any text between these two tags is considered to be *wrapped in HTML*. You will also notice the `<br>` tag within the string which forces the Line Break so as to create two lines.

A JLabel is very limited to what it can do and **without HTML** it can't really do anything bullet listed above and display a text file within a JLabel like this:

[image]

You will of course notice the Scrollbar in the above image. Yet another problem with the JLabel, it won't display Scrollbars if needed. You need to place the JLabel into a **JScrollPane** to have this feature since there may very well be files that are going to exceed the boundaries of your JLabel so you need to also consider this. Simple enough, not the end of the world.

The method provided below will read in the supplied text file and display it within the supplied JLabel. It will automatically wrap everything into HTML, Provide the title, Left pad all the text by 10 pixels, Line Wrap the text, handle Line Breaks, and take care of basic Indentation:

```
public void displayFileInJLabel(JLabel label, String filePath) {
    try {
        // Try With Resources (will auto close the reader).
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
            /* We use StringBuilder to build our HTML Wrapped 
               string to display within the JLabel.  */
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            // Get the width of our supplied JLabel
            int w = label.getWidth();

            /* Calculations for determininfg Line Wrap. 
               The (w / 4) is a modifiable offset.  */
            String width = String.valueOf((w - (w / 4))); 

            /* Deal with Line Wrap (JLabels don't do this) and
               set up Left Padding.  */
            sb.append("<html><body style='width: ").append(width).append("px; padding:10px;'>");

            /* Apply the Title Center of JLabel, Blue Color Text, 
               and Bold Font Style.The size of the text is determined 
               by the <h1> and </h1> tags.  */
            sb.append("<center><h1><font color=blue><b>").append(filePath).append("</b></font></h1></center><br>");

            // Read in File Lines one at a time.
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                /* Deal with multiple whitespaces (basic indenting etc) since HTML 
                   doesn't deal well with more than a single whitespace.  */
                line = line.replaceAll("\\s{4}", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");

                /* Deal with line breaks. JLabels won't deal with them since 
                   it is designed for a single line of text. We therefore
                   apply the HTML Line Break tag (<br>)at the end of each 
                   text file line to take care of this business.   */
                line+= "<br>";

                sb.append(line);
            }

            // Apply the closing tags to finish our HTML Wrapping.
            sb.append("</body></html>");

            /* Set the formated HTML text to the JLabel */
            label.setText(sb.toString());
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger("displayFileInJLabel() Method").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

If you remove all the commenting then it really isn't that much code but there is yet more to do. To build the form sample displayed above

- Create a new JFrame Form;
- Set it's **DefaultCloseOperation** property to **DISPOSE**;
- Set it's **AlwaysOnTop** property to **true**;
- before the Form is displayed set it's **SetLocationRelativeTo**
  property to **null**;
- Place a **JScrollPane** into the JFrame form. Have it take up the
  entire size of Form;
- Place a JLabel into the JScrollPane. Have it take up the entire size
  of the JScrollPane;
- Set the JLabel's **Background** color to **White**;
- Set the JLabel's **Opaque** property to **true**;
- Set the JLabel's **HorizontalAlignment** to **LEFT**;
- Set the JLabel's **VerticalAlighnment** to **TOP**;
- Make sure the JLabel **Text** property is **empty** (nothing);
- Copy and Paste the **displayFileInJLabel()** method into an
  accessible place. Within your JFrame Form Class will do if you like.
- Place a call to the **displayFileInJLabel()** method within the
  JFrame's **ComponentResized** event, something like this:

  ```
  displayFileInJLabel(jLabel1, "C:\\MyFiles\\LoremIpsum.txt");
  ```

  Better to have a class member variable hold the file path to view rather than hard coding it then fill this member variable in the Form's Class Constructor that would have a String Type parameter.

It's all a matter of what you really want to do. Using a **JTextArea** is still a better idea.